# How to remove lines with specific characters in asp?

Tags: asp.net

I write a code on the ASP.net as follows:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
            {
                TextBox1.Lines = TextBox1.Lines.Where(line => !line.Contains(" " + j + "%")).ToArray();
            }
```

I have error with "lines":

> Error 4   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Lines' and no extension method 'Lines' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can someone help me

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox  does not have a Lines property. You probably confused it with Winforms TextBox.

Comment: Well the error is pretty accurate cause there is no Lines property on a TextBox...there is however a Text property.  I'm not entirely sure what it is you're trying to accomplish though, can you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `TextBox` is *MultiLine* and you have 50 rows, you can split this by `Environment.NewLine` and check each row that way.

```
string[] lines = TextBox1.Text
            .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
            .Select(x => !x.Contains(" " + j + "%"))
            .ToArray();

TextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

If you can elaborate on what your intent is, it may help with a better answer.